# Debian missing firmware that should be present

Tags: debian, drivers, firmware, acer

I am currently switching from Windows to Linux on all of my Systems and now there is only my Laptop left. It is a Acer Nitro 5 AN517-52-514, on which I am trying to install Debian 12.0.

The problem: Whenever I try to start the install of debian, I am greeted by the following messages and unable to start normally. It just goes into recovery mode:

integrity: Problem loading x.509 certificate -65 
integrity: Problem loading x.509 certificate -65 
i915 0000:00:02.0: firmware: failed to load i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin (-2)
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-Quz-a0-hr-b0-59.ucode (-2)
(the same message with a few more other versions)
bluetooth hci0: firmware: failed to load intel/ibt-19-0-4.sfi (-2)
Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to load Intel firmware file (-2)

I am especially confused by the iwlwifi firmware missing, since I installed the package and by the i915 one, since I installed it after the guide on debian.org. I aquired the file for the ibt firmware, but do not know where to put it so it gets detected.
I have already tried installing firmware-linux-nonfree.

Comment: about iwlwifi: is there a non-failure message as well below the failure messages? It attemps to search for multiple versions until one is found. As long as one is found that's normal. So are you having non-functional hardware, or are you just asking about the messages? They are probably not related to going to recovery mode. So there's something else, more important, to search for in the messages.

Comment: do you have `firmware-iwlwifi` package installed